# How to read 'sk' parameter of facebook tabs(custom fan page)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook

Is der any way in which i can get sk parameter of facebook tab page.
For example if page URL is this http://www.facebook.com/FacebookStudio?sk=app_127337483972992
then i want value of sk.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The number following the sk= is the application ID of the app (aka page tab).  So just use a indexOf('sk=') command to find the beginning part and strip out using a Left() or a SubString() command.  Or you can go crazy and use Regex, extra points for doing it with Regex  :)

Comment: But can we read the parameters of parent frame,the page tabs is an iframe in facebook page. Anyways i got the solution of my problem ,i will pass the app id to page tab url as get parameter.